# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'zeroes'

Tags: python, numpy

This is the error I am getting. I have imported numpy as np in my main code. There is no other usage of the phrase np besides when using to indicate numpy. I have spelt it correctly everywhere in my code as np.zeroes(nS) where nS is an int. I reinstalled anaconda and updated it but still the error persists. What do I do ?

```
  File "C:\Users\91845\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 313, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'zeroes'
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax is `np.zeros(nS)`, without `e`

cf. [`numpy.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) documentation

*NB. the best practice is to search/read the documentation before reinstalling your system, that would save you a lot of time ;)*

Comment: OMG thank you so much. I did read it but I did not even realize I was spelling it wrong constantly. I'll keep this in mind thank you so much